# What is the meaning of "due allowance"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> ...when ***due allowance*** is made for the wear of existing
>   specimens, they might well be thought to have been struck *al pezzo*
>   rather than *al marco*. (Macdowall, David W., 1965. *The Dynasty of
>   the Later Indo-Parthians*, p140)

What is the meaning of "due allowance"?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually related to the definition of [**due**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/due_1) definition 6:

> **suitable/right**
>   [only before noun] (formal) that is suitable or right in the circumstances
>
> After **due consideration**, we have decided to appoint Mr Davis to the job.
>   to make **due allowance** for something (British English)
>   He was charged with driving without **due care** and attention.

So the conclusion in the quote is made on the condition that *the wear of existing specimens* would be considired as appropriate in that kind of situation.

*due consideration* could also be used in your quote without changing the meaning.